Can't configure systemd:postfix on pacemaker to work properly
Objective: I have a cluster managed by the pacemaker, I want my postfix resource to depend on clamav-daemon.service and mailscanner.service. If either one of these two resources fail, the IP jumps.
I researched and found that I can use systemd to configure parameters like "BindsTo=" and "after=" which can be useful to my case.
I used these commands to configure my resource on pacemaker: (currently testing on a single machine to see if I can have this configuration to work inside a cluster)
pcs resource create postfixmail systemd:postfix
pcs resource clone postfixmail clone-max=1 clone-node-max=1
pcs constraint location postfixmail-clone prefers mailt02=INFINITY

This is the result I get:
Failed Resource Actions:
  * postfixmail_start_0 on mailt02 'error' (1): call=51, status='complete', exitreason='', last-rc-change='2024-09-26 11:38:07 +01:00', queued=0ms, exec=456ms

This is my systemd/postfix.service file configuration:
[Unit]
Description=Postfix Mail Transport Agent
Conflicts=sendmail.service exim4.service
ConditionPathExists=/etc/postfix/main.cf
BindsTo=mailscanner.service clamav-daemon.service
After=mailscanner.service clamav-daemon.service 

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/postfix start
ExecReload=/usr/sbin/postfix reload

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

This is what "systemctl status postfix.service" gives me:
mailscanner.service: Found ordering cycle on postfix.service/start
mailscanner.service: Found dependency on mailscanner.service/start
mailscanner.service: Unable to break cycle starting with mailscanner.service/start
mailscanner.service: Found ordering cycle on postfix.service/start
mailscanner.service: Found dependency on mailscanner.service/start
mailscanner.service: Unable to break cycle starting with mailscanner.service/start


         

I'm here to ask for some help and guidance to solve this problem. I also accept suggestion of other ways to reach my objective.
Thanks!

You don't need to create a clone of the postfix resource if you only want a single instance of postfix running in the cluster at a given time.
Instead of trying to use the postfix systemd unit to create dependencies between clamav-daemon and mailscanner, and postfix, you should manage those services and dependencies in Pacemaker using Pacemaker's resource colocation and order constraints.
# create resources
pcs resource create postfixmail systemd:postfix
pcs resource create mailscanner systemd:mailscanner
pcs resource create clamav systemd:clamav-daemon

# order the resources (assuming clamav-daemon, then mailscanner, then postfix)
pcs constraint order clamav then mailscanner
pcs constraint order mailscanner then postfixmail

# colocate them with each other
pcs constraint colocation add mailscanner with clamav
pcs constraint colocation add postfixmail with mailscanner

